# jQuery: append form input

Tags: jquery, forms, input, append

here is my html output:

```
<script language="javascript">
  function append_suggestion() {
    $('input[name="cn"]').append($('#rand-character').val());
  }
</script>

<form name="form" action="/search/results" method="get" class="search-form" id="search-autocomplete">
  <input size="28" class="search-field" id="cn" name="cn" type="text" value="" />      <input type="submit" name="" value="" class="button" />
</form>

<a href="#" id="rand-character" onclick="append_suggestion()">link</a>
```

After clicking the link nothing happens (it's supposed to insert link text into the input field). How to correct this link behavior?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Also: use ´<script type="text/javascript">´ instead of ´<script language="javascript">´

Comment: I don't believe you can append to an input tag: append() inserts DOM elements to the matched element (in this case, all input fields with the name 'cn'). If you're trying to insert the contents of the #rand-character element, try using val(). Also, you should use '#cn' instead of 'input[name="cn"]' if you're only interested in that single input element: he latter must do a more exhaustive search of the DOM, which is considerably slower.

Comment: @Jan, sorry, edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var cnEl = $('#cn');
cnEl.val(cnEl.val() + " " + $('#rand-character').text());
```